# Calculate Memory utilization at node level[prometheus]

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I need to visualise the total memory usage of a node in grafana. 
I have the metric `container_memory_working_set_bytes` available from prometheus.Using only this metric how can i calculate the total memory used by a node which contains various containers.

Comment: It would depend on your prometheus config. But you can have a sum like this. sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes {kubernetes_io_hostname="$node"}). Note that this will not give you the memory used by other processes on the node if any (including system resources)